# Erro de memória ao gerar planilha com o PHPExcel

Tags: php, array, memória, cache, phpexcel

Estou com problemas na geração de planilhas do Excel utilizando o PHPExcel quando o número de registros é muito grande a memória é insuficiente para processar a tarefa, existe alguma forma de melhorar a criação desse arquivo através de algum sistema de cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro que aumente a memória no `php.ini`. O meu é `php7.0` no `Ubuntu 14`, fica em  `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

Na linha 389 coloquei assim:

```
Memory_limit = 768M
```

Pra editar o `php.ini` sugiro que use o `vi` no Ubuntu.

Comment: Essa é uma das soluções, aumentar o uso de memória do PHP, porém gostaria de outro meio para solucionar o problema, quando for hospedar um sistema em um servidor provavelmente terei limitação de uso de memória.

Answer (score 0):

É possível aumentar a memória no arquivo php.ini, localizado por exemplo na minha máquina em:

```
 /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-development
```

Ou então diretamente no código php

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');
```